SQL: query to select all records from join table
I have join table (from relation OneToMany-ManyToOne):



warehouse_group_id
warehouse_id




1
1


2
1


4
1


4
2


5
1


5
2



I want to receive list of all warehouse_id for warehouse_id 2. For example for warehouse_id = 2 I want to know all warehouse_id values that belong to one warehouse_group_id. Eg. for warehouse_id = 2 I want to receive warehouse_id 1,2 because warehouse_id = 2 is part of warehouse_group_id 4 and 5 and in warehouse_group_id 4 and 5 there are warehouse_id 1,2
What query should I prepare?

What if row 1, 1 didn't exist, do you still want to see warehouse_id 1 ? In other words, do you care that the other warehouse_id has any of the warehouse_group_id, or all of the warehouse_group_id or all and no other warehouse_group_id as compared to the warehouse_id you input?

You can use 'self join' technique:
select distinct wh.warehouse_id
from w 
join w as wh on w.warehouse_group_id = wh.warehouse_group_id
where w.warehouse_id = 2;

Try it on fiddle

SELECT warehouse_id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE warehouse_group_id IN 
(SELECT warehouse_group_id FROM mytable WHERE warehouse_id = 2)

Untested yet, but this should be what you're looking for.

Perhaps DISTINCT too?

Thank you. The DISTINCT clause is definitely an improvement even though the original answer was technically correct. P.S. mostly irrelevant as the accepted answer is even better.

SELECT A.warehouse_id 
FROM #Temp_Result A
WHERE A.warehouse_group_id = 4


